# Two buttons displayed when applying Dojo style to button

Tags: html, css, button, dojo, styles

When i apply DOJO style to a button, DOJO styled button is displayed along with a small normal button, Can anyone help me with this. Below is the complete HTML code. Thanks in advance.[image]

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
@import "http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.2.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
</style>

<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async : true,
        parseOnLoad : true
    }
</script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script>
    require([ "dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button" ], function(parser) {
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" />
    Greetings
    </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm noticing two things here:

You're closing your button twice:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" />
    Greetings
</button>
```

Look at the end of the first line, you're ending your `<button>` using `/>`, which means you're closing the button as well. Replace that by:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
    Greetings
</button>
```

---

The second thing I noticed is that you're loading an old version of the Tundra theme. You're using Dojo **1.9.2**, but you're using the Tundra theme of **1.2.0**. Try to replace your stylesheet by:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dimitri, stylesheet was the problem. Thanks it worked.